# The last Spring boot validation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, validation

I'm a beginner in spring boot and I found a problem with validation It doesn't work and I tried spring validation also hibernate dependency. I have the last version of spring boot 2.7.2
I add
 `<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId> </dependency>`
to my pom.xml but when I add @NotNull to my bean gave me an error, and showed me there's not a @NonNull Annotation.

Comment: What specific problem do you have? Can you show an example of what the problem looks like in code? What are your expectations for your code?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. In my case, there was a problem with my pom. I had a dependency on the hibernate-validator. So I removed and worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will test it and I will reply to you.